# how to add smooth scrool transitions for Bootstrap scroll spy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have developed single page website and used bootstrap scroll spy when i click on nav item border bottom  is not displaying before  for this issue
i have added script now there is no issue in this.

But when i click nav link smooth scroll is not working link directly placing  to 
particular section without smooth scroll  please anyone help me on this

Reference : http://floretmedia.net/temp/pbee/

```js
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var headerHeight = $('header').innerHeight();
    scrollTop: target.offset().top - headerHeight //offset height of header here too.
  });
</script>
```

```html
<body id="lcp1" data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="70">
<header>
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="header-right">
      <div class="navbar-holder"> <!-- navbar-holder -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default"> <!-- navbar-inverse -->         
           <div class="navbar-header">
             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed blue" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              </button>
              <div class="ease cf">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">
                   <img src="images/logo.png" alt="sfatech Logo">
                </a>
              </div> 
           </div> <!-- /.navbar-header -->
             <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse cf"> <!-- nav-collapse -->
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right navbrdr">
                  <li class="active"><a href="./">HOME </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#features"> FEATURES </a></li>
                  <li><a href="#plans">PRICING</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
                  <li><a href="includes/enquiry_form.php" class="signup fancybox" data-fancybox-type="iframe">SIGN UP</a></li>                 
                </ul> <!-- /.navbar-nav -->

             </div> <!--/.nav-collapse -->           
         </nav> <!-- /.navbar-inverse -->
      </div> <!-- /.navbar-holder -->
   </div><!-- header-right -->
  </div><!-- custom-container -->
</header>
```

Comment: any errors checking the page with Chrome Inspector? Any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this one

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="#"]').forEach(anchor => {
        anchor.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            .preventDefault();
                document.querySelector(this.getAttribute('href')).scrollIntoView({
                    behavior: 'smooth'
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

without javascript, add this code in your CSS file

```
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```